# Using route parameter in razor pages over a certain length causing invalid url error

Tags: razor, url-routing, asp.net-core-3.1

I am trying to pass an error message to my error page in razor using a routing parameter named {error}. But I keep getting an invalid url error. I've chalked it up to being the length of the url parameter I'm passing as my routing parameter which is causing this issue.

But I don't understand this, since the valid length of a url is 2048 characters. And the length of a string is significantly higher. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

This returns an invalid url error. Total characters: 404, url parameter: 373

http://localhost123/Error/An%20error%20occurred%20while%20updating%20the%20entries.%20See%20the%20inner%20exception%20for%20details.The%20INSERT%20statement%20conflicted%20with%20the%20FOREIGN%20KEY%20constraint%20"FK_VthaFormsWorkflow_VthaForms".%20The%20conflict%20occurred%20in%20database%20"MyDWPApps",%20table%20"dbo.VthaForms",%20column%20%27Id%27.%20The%20statement%20has%20been%20terminated./True

[image]

if i remove the last sentence, the url is valid. Total characters: 359, url parameter: 328

http://localhost123/Error/An%20error%20occurred%20while%20updating%20the%20entries.%20See%20the%20inner%20exception%20for%20details.The%20INSERT%20statement%20conflicted%20with%20the%20FOREIGN%20KEY%20constraint%20"FK_VthaFormsWorkflow_VthaForms".%20The%20conflict%20occurred%20in%20database%20"MyDWPApps",%20table%20"dbo.VthaForms",%20column%20%27Id%27./True

[image]

```
//Error.cshtml

@page   "{error}/{hidenavbar:bool=false}"
@model ErrorModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Error";

    if (Model.HideNavbar)
    {
        Layout = "_LayoutHideNavbar";
    }
}

<div class="header-title text-center">
    <h1 class="title">Error</h1>
</div>

<div class="card w-75 text-center mx-auto p-4">
    <div><b>Time of Error:</b> @DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString()</div>
    <div class="text-danger"><b>Error message:</b> @Model.Error</div>
    <br />
</div>
```

```
//Error.cshtml.cs

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace VehicleTakeHomeApp.Pages
{
    public class ErrorModel : PageModel
    {
        [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
        public bool HideNavbar { get; set; }

        [BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
        public string Error { get; set; }

        private readonly ILogger<ErrorModel> _logger;

        public ErrorModel(ILogger<ErrorModel> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public void OnGet()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you really need to give these details to your end user? This is well known as a security risk

Comment: even if its for an intranet site?

Comment: Yes, even for intranet sites, this is a disclosure of informations and employees could keep a grudge against their employer for many reasons. I suggest to log the exact error message in a file and give to your user an error message instead

Comment: dangit, i have to change up a lot of logic then. And just to make sure, I can't log to a file using the out of box logger that .netcore provides right?

Comment: nlog, log4net, serilog can be easily integrated in the logging subsystem engineered for asp.net core. Usually you can find detailed instructions in their site how to use the Startup.cs and Program.cs to initialize the logging

Comment: Also, is that _'/True'_ at the end of the URL legit?

Comment: yeah, i have an nlog solution integrated in with another project that I can reference. I was just hoping I could use the out of the box logger to log to file. yeah the true works, it passes into the HideNavbar parameter. Thanks for your suggestion. My boss had mentioned it to me before, but i completely ignored it until you mentioned it again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will end up using nlog logger and transferring all internal exception messages to the nlog logger output to file. All user errors will display a generic error message as per @Steve's suggestion.